# Excel Table References

Tags: excel

I have the following data formatted as a table in Excel:

```
First Name  Last Name   Full Name
Simon       King        Simon King
Antoine     French      Antoine French
```

In cell C2 I have the formula C2 (Excel 2007):

```
 =Table1[[#This Row],[First Name]]& " "&Table1[[#This Row],[Last Name]]
```

which returns Simon King

However on Excel 2010 the following formula returns the same result:

```
=[@[First Name]]&" "&[@[Last Name]]
```

Is there a different referencing technique in newer versions of Excel or is there a setting as to what syntax can be used. I have a macro which users the latter, but won't work on some other users' Excel. The issue is that I use the latter in macro which creates an error in later versions.

Comment: Simon - I'm not sure it matters which version you are using 2010 or later.  What you have in the first item is a formula that includes the table references while the second just assumes that the data and the formula are in the same table.  Is this important for some reason?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. Initially the formula was outside the table, which is why it references the table. The main difference is the former uses [#This Row], where as the later uses  [@

Answer (score 0):

**In Excel 2016**: The referencing technique is `=[@FirstName]&" "&[@LastName]`.

Also from your post, I presume you are trying to set the above formula for C2,C3...Cn column values using macro. In that case, how about using a macro that does the same without setting the formula.

```
Sub concatName()
Worksheets("Sheet5").Select
Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
For i = 2 To LastRow
    Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value & " " & Cells(i, 2).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Dhamo. You are correct. I am trying to use it in a macro. I have only started to used formatted tables to simplify the macros. So if I have to I will revert to something as you have above, but would still like to know why the referencing syntax is different. (Root/Cause analysis.) Also using the table column names means it doesn't matter too much if the column orders change.